# Running Unit Tests in Test Bundle in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to write a parser in Python for a special text file format. To get an idea how to structure the code I looked into the source code of the JSON parser which is part of the Python standard library (`Python/Lib/json`).

In this json directory there is a `tests` directory which holds a number of unit tests. I replaced the json tests with my tests but now I do not know how to call them.

Looking into the directory there is a `__init__.py` file making it a module and inside of this file there is the following code snippet for running the tests:

```
here = os.path.dirname(__file__)

def test_suite():
    suite = additional_tests()
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    for fn in os.listdir(here):
        if fn.startswith("test") and fn.endswith(".py"):
            modname = "json.tests." + fn[:-3]
            __import__(modname)
            module = sys.modules[modname]
            suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(module))
    return suite

def additional_tests():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for mod in (json, json.encoder, json.decoder):
        suite.addTest(doctest.DocTestSuite(mod))
    suite.addTest(TestPyTest('test_pyjson'))
    suite.addTest(TestCTest('test_cjson'))
    return suite

def main():
    suite = test_suite()
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))
    main()
```

My problem is now how are these unit tests executed? I am confused because the `if __name__ == '__main__':` if clause validates to true if this file is called directly and not being imported as a module. However as it is in the `__init__.py` file of the module it should be executed right after import.

Should an `import tests` in the python console start all the unit tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First**: the `__init__.py` file in a directory marks the directory as a package and all other files with the `.py` ending therein are modules.

**Second**: To validate the `__name__ == '__main__'` conditional you have to execute the file. So a simple `import` won't do.

For further question on package and module structure i would suggest ro read the [Official Python Documentation on Packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

The unittests are structured into testsuites, which can contain one ore more TestCases which consists of one or more tests.

The tests are usually methods of a TestCase derived class. You can either run the tests by defining a `runTest()` method or defining multiple `test_*` methods, which will be executed autmatically. To execute a Unittest you can either use the convenience function `unittest.main()` which basicaly tries to construct a testsuite, testresult and testrunner object by using default-rules.

The execution of your unittest itself is done by the testrunner object. The standard testrunner-class is `TextTestRunner`, which uses a `TextTestResult`-class to store the testresults and prints them to `stdout`. See [Official unittest Documentation for unittest.main()](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) for the simplest variant.

### Summary

**1)** A unittest is basically a TestSuite containing one ore more TestCases:

```
TestSuite      <---executed by--- TestRunner
   + TestCaseA                        |
       +test_a()                      |
       +test_b()             stores test-results 
           ...                      into
       +test_z()                      |
    + TestCaseB                       V
    + TestCaseC                  TestResult
```

**2)** The TestCases are subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`. You can create a TestSuite, by using a loader (e.g.: `unittest.defaultTestLoader`) which is basically a factory for a testsuite, or you can add the TestCases manually (`suite.addTest(test) / suite.addTests(tests)` - `tests` may be `TestCases` or even other `TestSuites`) or by combining those two methods.

**3)** To execute a testsuite you use a `unittest.TestRunner`-object which saves the results in a `unittest.TestResult` object.

Normaly you would be using `unittest.TextTestRunner`-object to get a simple output of the testresults to stdout.

That's excatly what happens also in your main-routine:

```
def main():
    suite = test_suite()                #1 create a TestSuite object
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()  #2 create a TextTestRunner object
    runner.run(suite)                   #3 executes the TestSuite with TestSuite
                                        #  build by the function test_suite()
```

To execute your testsuite you would have then to execute `python __init__.py` .

Comment: Thanks for getting the nomenclature right, I will change my question accordingly.

Comment: But how are the tests executed?

Comment: I updated my answer and hopefully addressed all or at least most of your concerns.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote so much explanation, that i overlooked your correct usage of the test_suite() function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so to run the main function, I would call `python __init__.py` on the command line? I have problems understanding this part of the testing. I would love give you more than one up vote for this great summary.

Comment: Exactly, if the posted main-funcion resides in `__init__.py` you would have to execute `python __init__.py`. I added this to my explanation and hope this answers your question(s).