# Python unittest results file

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I use next command to run my tests:

> python -m unittest discover -p "*.py"

It writes test's result to stdout. But I would like get result as file (if possible in html)
Now I get it using PyCharm and it works perfectly but I need to run tests on remote machines automatically and get report of course. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write the output into a file using `>`:

```
python -m unittest discover -p "*.py" > results.txt
```

This is not Python specific but UNIX which allows you to redirect standard output to a file (which is what `> filename` does).

Comment: @Eugene: well, yes. In that case you need to add 2>&1 at the end of the line. It'll then include errors as well as regular output.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have to subclass the `TestRunner` class and write your own output implementation (If a stdout redirection isn't what you have in mind).

A basic [overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8728973/1107807) of the included unittest machination from another answer.

In principle a `TestRunner` uses the provided information of your `TestSuite` and stores it's results into a `TestResult` object. Each class can be modified to your suits.

An example for a [HTMLTestRuner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html) from Wai Yip Tung.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple send the results to a file

```
python -m unittest discover -p "*.py" > output.txt
```

If you need another format, there are a variety of packages: See this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162682/display-python-unittest-results-in-nice-tabular-form)
For example [unittest-xml-reporting](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest-xml-reporting) will give JUnit style output for e.g. a CI server.